# How does the AbstractEventLoop method create_server work in events module of asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

[image]

How does the AbstractEventLoop method create_server work in events module of asyncio?

Answer (score 2):

`asyncio` uses not `AbstractEventLoop` but derived classes: `SelectorEventLoop` (and `ProactorEventLoop` for Windows).

You never instantiate the event loop by calling it's constructor but use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` / `asyncio.new_event_loop()` for it.

Please take a look on [asyncio/base_events.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py) and [asyncio/selector_events.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/selector_events.py) for example of actual implementation.